# Question on exponential martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I was reading the first proof here on exponential martingale, 
https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/lecture-23-time-changed-martingales-and-planar-brownian-motion/

It says that
 
"Let $
N_t=e^{i\lambda M_t +\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 t}$. By using Ito’s formula, we obtain that for $s \le t, N_t =N_s +\int_s^t N_u dM_u.$"

I tried working out the same thing using Ito's formula but what i got was $N_t =N_s +i\lambda\int_s^t N_u dM_u.$

I have the extra $i\lambda$ popping up in front of the integral, can someone help see what i might be doing wrong?

Many Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong about your calculation, the extra "$\imath \lambda$" is correct.

Comment: Ah thanks! For a while I thought I must have gotten something wrong!

Comment: i was thinking for a while that if that was true then it runs counter to the fact that in essence why it's an exponential martingale is because we want d( e^ax ) = a*e^ax in normal calculus to hold in a similar fashion for the stochastic calculus version.